# Anonymous function arguments and the order they are passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

**Explanation:**

Something I have not been able to get my head around with anonymous functions is their arguments.

Say we are using `jQuery.each();`

I know that if we call `each()` and use what I would call an `anonymous callback function` 
 i.e.

```
$.each('p', function(index, item){
```

I can 'grab' the index and the element using an anonymous function, as seen above. Using this I could then do something like

```
var array = [];

$.each('p', function(index, item){
    if(index % 3 === 0) array.push(item);
});
```

Using the anonymous function I grabbed the index of the current element it was running the `each` against and then `push`-ed it into an array `if` I could divide the `index` by three, or basically every 3 items.

**Question:**

Do all methods throw different parameters for us to 'catch' with anonymous functions, or do they all follow a strict pattern of `(index, element, etc.)`

If they are all different, is there a way to find out what data is being passed from a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't count on the arguments always being the same, as what makes sense depends a lot on context.

There is a very easy way to find out what arguments will be given: [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) :)

For example, [the documentation for `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) reads

> `.each( function )` Returns: `jQuery`
>   Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.
>
> `function`
>   Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
>   A function to execute for each matched element.

Comment: What would the "technical term" for these arguments be? Just so I know what to look for in the documentation!

Comment: They're just function arguments, no different from arguments to any other function. However, a function passed like this has a special name: it's a *callback function*.

Comment: OH, it says at the top of the page for the method :) `.each()` is:

_Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )_, thanks Tomas

Comment: Yup. The first thing you need to learn when you start using a new library, is how they structure their documentation. jQuery is no different in this aspect :)

Comment: To make matters complicated the ordering of the arguments between `$.each` and JS's native `forEach` is different. `$each` is index then element, `forEach` is element then index (then array). So watch out for that.